# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am very new to the Spring AOP. I've developed below code, just to run Circles getName method before LoggingAspect. Also I wanted all xml beans to be written into Annotations how we can do that? How to resolved below error?

I think I've provided sufficient information. Any quick help from experts?

Here is the my project structure:

[image]

The error I am getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.aop.AOPMain.main(AOPMain.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getPointcut(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:466)
    ... 10 more
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean name="triangle" class="com.spring.aop.model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="Triangle name" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="circle" class="com.spring.aop.model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="Circle name" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="shapeService" class="com.spring.aop.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName" />

    <bean name="loggingAspect" class="com.spring.aop.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
</beans>
```

Circle.java:

```
package com.spring.aop.model;

public class Circle {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Triangle.java

```
package com.spring.aop.model;

public class Triangle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

LoggingAspect.java:

```
package com.spring.aop.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(public String getName())")
    public void LoggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get method called");
    }
}
```

AOPMain.java

```
package com.spring.aop;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.spring.aop.service.ShapeService;

public class AOPMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        ShapeService shapeService = ctx.getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
        System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
    }
}
```

ShapeService.java:

```
package com.spring.aop.service;

import com.spring.aop.model.Circle;
import com.spring.aop.model.Triangle;

public class ShapeService {
    private Circle circle;
    private Triangle triangle;

    public Circle getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }
    public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }
    public Triangle getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }
    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }
}
```

I tried to developed Annotation class, also I'm not sure how we can developed Autowire byName?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.spring.aop.aspect.LoggingAspect;
import com.spring.aop.model.Circle;
import com.spring.aop.model.Triangle;
import com.spring.aop.service.ShapeService;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="circle")
    public Circle MyCircle(){
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setName("Triangle name");
        return circle;
    }

    @Bean(name="triangle")
    public Triangle myTriangle(){
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
        triangle.setName("Circle name");
        return triangle;
    }

    @Bean(name="shapeService")
    public ShapeService shapeService(){
        return new ShapeService(); 
    }

    @Bean(name="loggingAspect")
    public LoggingAspect loggingAspect(){
        return new LoggingAspect();
    }
}
```

But its giving me

```
May 14, 2015 1:44:23 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15e6e48b: startup date [Thu May 14 01:44:23 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spring.aop.AOPMain.main(AOPMain.java:14)
```

Any quick guidance?

Answer (score 1):

It looks simple solution, just add following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here is a missing dependency. Try adding:

```
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.8.5</version>
```

to your POM.

Comment: Hi - Thank you. How we can convert xml file to annotations?

Comment: @user4567570 not sure which XMLs you're referring to. I suggest creating a new question for this - it's beyond the scope of your original post.

Comment: Hi - No, I've already asked about it " Also I wanted all xml beans to be written into Annotations how we can do that? " in my post. Please guide.

Comment: Have you looked at any of Spring's documentation on annotation config? It's fairly straightforward to create an analogue of your application context using @Bean annorations